# juju, dnsmasq and `.localdomain`

Tags: juju, dnsmasq

I'm trying to setup an Ubuntu private cloud infrastructure on a virtual environment via learning from

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/TestingMAAS and
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure#Ubuntu_Cloud_Infrastructure_with_MAAS_and_Juju

All have been done but I have a small issue; I see that `juju` has been added `.localdomain` to node's host-names during deploying of various charms. In another side of coin, my `dnsmasq` on the `maas server` node cannot resolve this new one changed host-name to a suitable IP address. e.g. `juju debug-hooks nova-volume/0` says me `node-aabbccddeef8.localdomain cannot be resolved` or for example when I try to log-in to `openstack-dashboard` web UI, it says me an internal error which after my review, it's because it cannot resolve `keystone` node, `node-aabbccddeef5.localdomain` to any IP.

Why `juju` behaves like this? Can I say `juju` to roll-back the host-names? or any clean solution to learn `dnsmasq` to resolve these too?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `domain=localdomain` to `dnsmasq.conf` file which sorts the problem out.